# Excel "This workbook contains links to other data sources"

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I am getting this pop-up in Excel 2003, "This workbook contains links to other data sources", with the options to "Update" or "Don't Update". The workbook is using VLOOKUP to get information from another workbook.

Is there any way to disable this in the workbook?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Automatic update and no message

To suppress the message and to automatically update the links when you open a workbook in **Excel 2002** or in **Excel 2003**, follow these steps:

1. On the **Tools** menu, click **Options**, and then click the **Edit** tab.
2. Click to clear the **Ask to update automatic links** check box.

<sub>For **Excel 2007**, follow these steps:</sub>

1. Click **Microsoft Office Button**, and then click **Excel Options**.
2. Click **Advanced**.
3. Under **General**, click to clear the **Ask to update automatic links** check box.

Notes: When the **Ask to update automatic links** check box is cleared, the links are automatically updated. Additionally, no message appears. This option applies to the current user only and affects every workbook that the current user opens. Other users of the same workbooks are not affected.

---

### Manual update and no message

If you are sharing this workbook with other people who will not have access to the sources of the updated links, you can turn off updating and the prompt for updating. To suppress the message and leave the links (not updated) until you choose to update them, follow these steps:

1. On **Edit** menu, click **Links**.
     <sub>(Note: In Excel 2007, click **Edit Links** in the **Connections** group on the **Data** tab.)</sub>
2. Click **Startup Prompt**.
3. Click the **Don't display the alert and don't update automatic links** option.

Warning: If you choose not to update the links and not to receive the message, users of the workbook will not know that the data is out of date. This choice affects all users of the workbook. However, this choice applies only to that particular workbook.

To update the links manually, follow these steps:

1. On **Edit** menu, click **Links**.
     <sub>(Note: In Excel 2007, click **Edit Links** in the **Connections** group on the **Data** tab.)</sub>
2. Click **Update Values**.
3. Click **Close**.

Source: [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826921)